# Different DNS name resolution for same server

Tags: domain-name-system, hosts

I am working on an internal facing wiki that is hosted on a linux box in the office that also holds our backup-server roll. The name of this server is 'backup-server' and DNS resolves this  to the correct IP (192.168.1.103).

I would like for the users accessing the wiki to be able to go to 'wiki.domain.com' where the domain is our internal office domain. I thought this would be a simple DNS A record change but it seems to be not working as I thought it would.

The other way that i have made this work on the few computers I use while developing the wiki is to just edit the 'hosts' file with: wiki.domain.com 192.168.1.103

I have a Win Server 2012 DNS server and would like to edit the DNS there so that i can easily push out the change to all computers in the network but I cant seem to get this to work.

How would i go about getting this FQDN pointing to the correct IP?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows DNS Server, but every other DNS server on the market can have multiple names for any given ip address. Try just creating a new A record for wiki.domain.com and just ignore the existing backup-server DNS name.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you did or what the result was. Did you add an A record for `wiki` to your internal DNS zone? Did you configure the appropriate host headers (or the equivalent) on the web server?

Comment: This is what `CNAME` is for.

Comment: Solved the problem... I was adding the A record to the 'office' sub domain. So for instance I was trying to get to wiki.domian.com but i was setting the A record to wiki.office.domain.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you need is a CNAME record that points to the backup server address.

That is presuming that when you try to resolve backup-server.domain.com you get the 192 address.

Therefore, if your Win2012 server is the domain server for your domain.com then you can add the record in there, but I am thinking you more likely have another DNS that is handling the domain.com names for you and that is where you would need to add the address if you truly wanted wiki.domain.com.

If you add a CNAME record into that DNS then it will most likely give an external address for your backup-server (if indeed it is visible in the primary domain).

Comment: I accepted this answer because this would be the way to do it. I was simply entering the records into the wrong sub-domain.